# Angular auth guard not redirecting when returning Promise<UrlTree>

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, angular2-routing

I have created an auth guard for my `/sign-in` and `/verify-email` routes to only allow access to the users that are not logged in or havent verified their email:

```js
export const signInGuard: CanActivateFn = (activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<UrlTree | boolean> => {
  const router = inject(Router);
  const authenticationService = inject(AuthenticationService);

  const routeToResolve = activatedRouteSnapshot.url[0].path;

  console.log(routeToResolve)

  return firstValueFrom(authenticationService.onAuthStateChanged$)
    .then(user => {
      if (routeToResolve === 'verify-email') {
        if (!user) {
          return router.parseUrl('/sign-in');  // ### the issue is here ###
        } else if (user.emailVerified) {
          return router.parseUrl('/');
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        if (user) {
          return router.parseUrl('/');
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
};
```

The log from the console when logging the `routeToResolve` variable:

```
sign-in.guard.ts:12 verify-email
user.service.ts:21 [User Service]
user.service.ts:22 null
sign-in.guard.ts:12 sign-in
```

The guard works fine for all cases except for when the user is null and they are trying to access `/verify-email`. My expected behavior was to redirect the user in this case to `/sign-in`. Instead of this behavior, the user stays on the same route (`/verify-email`) with a blank white screen.

When I replace `return router.parseUrl('/sign-in')` with `return router.parseUrl('/')`, the user is correctly redirected, which tells me that the logic is executed correctly. But when i use `return router.parseUrl('/sign-in')`, it does not work.

I have also tried replacing that line of the code with:

```js
return router.navigateByUrl('/sign-in').then(() => false);
```

Which still resulted in the same buggy behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White page usually means that guard is hung up, due to some observable not emitting/completing. From logs it seems that you're redirected from 'verify-email' to 'sign-in' route, then this guards is checked again, but doesn't let you throught. Any chance that authenticationService.onAuthStateChanged$ doesn't emit any value the second time, and you're just hung up on it?

If not, maybe there's some other guard on 'sign-in' route that doesn't work well?

You could add a console log inside .then block, it would give you more information on what's happening

Comment: Thanks that was exactly the issue! the observable wasnt emitting anything on the second run.